# Nginx reverse proxy URL getting rewritten

Tags: nginx, jenkins, reverse-proxy, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am using nginx reverse proxy with ingress object to route my requests to kubernetes pod.

With the below config in place, when I place a request to my LB url http://myservices.myorg.com/jenkins

My request is going to http://myservices.myorg.com/login?from=%2F
But i want it to go to http://myservices.myorg.com/jenkins/login?from=%2F

So after I manually replaced to above correct path, all the resources like css, js are rendered with wrong path as http://myservices.myorg.com/static/beacae7e/css/simple-page.css

But it must be http://myservices.myorg.com/jenkins/static/beacae7e/css/simple-page.css

Similarly, after I logged in (I think http POST method) it is going to home page (in browser it changes from 
http://myservices.myorg.com/jenkins/login  to
http://myservices.myorg.com/jenkins

But all the resources rendered again are with wrong path (without /jenkins) -
http://myservices.myorg.com/static/beacae7e/css/layout-common.css

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myservices.myorg.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /jenkins
        backend:
           serviceName: jenkins
           service port: 80
```

And below is nginx.conf -

```
http {
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ip-10-118-6-35.ec2.internal;
     location /jenkins {
       proxy_pass https://backend_nodes_jenkins/;
      }
   }
 upstream backend_nodes_jenkins {
    server 10.102.194.242:80;
  }
}
```

As you can see in above nginx.conf , in proxy_pass I am having slash at the end of the URL since I should not pass /jenkins to my pod.

So this is working as expected but only issue is get requests are rewriting my url I believe. Please help.

Comment: Looks like Jenkins will generate hyperlinks like this. Read from this page - https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Hyperlinks+in+HTML

So not sure how to proceed..

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out by passing as env variable in docker CMD - JENKINS_OPTS="--prefix=/jenkins"